# Nested div ids - Having trouble with styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I am trying to style a div that is nested in some ofter divs and having some trouble. Below is the code and css I am attempting to use. If you could show me the correct css tag to style the element called #cleanse I would appreciate it.

```
<!-- Header starts here -->
<header id="header">
    <div class="align">
        <!-- Logo start here -->
        <div id="logo">
            <?php if(get_option( 'ms_plain_logo')=="true" ) { ?>
             <h1><a class="text_logo" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" data-rel="home"><?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1> 
            <?php } else { ?>
             <h1><a class="img_logo" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" data-rel="home"></a></h1> 
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Logo ends here -->
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <?php $args=array(
          'theme_location'=>'primary-navigation',
          'container' => 'nav',
          'container_id' => 'navigation-wrapper',
          'menu_id' => 'navigation',
          'fallback_cb' => false
        ); ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
        <?php if(!has_nav_menu( 'primary-navigation')) { ?>
        <nav id="navigation-wrapper">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- Navbar ends here -->
        <div id="cleanse">
<a href="link" target="_blank">
<img src="img"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Header ends here -->
#cleanse { top: 55px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do want to do? Add a margin-top or something?

This only works with position:

```
#cleanse { top: 55px; }
```

Try this:

```
#cleanse { margin-top: 55px; }
```

Also the css should be placed in the header:

```
<style>
/* your rules here */
</style>
```

Comment: I would like to nudge it down a little bit. Right now I don't know how far down the page it is starting, so I wanted to change it to 55px and then adjust from there. Usually I use firebug to adjust things and then add it to my code but it doesn't look like any styles are being applied to this element yet.

Comment: also thanks for taking the time to answer. :) The "margin-top" change did finally effect the element. However it also effected the rest of the header elements. Is there anyway to make sure it only styles the specific #cleanse div?

Comment: hm, is not easy without an example... what you could try is "padding-top" instead of the margin :-) Also what you can try is give the parent element an "position:relative;" and give them #cleanse div a "position:absolute;" and then you can adjust it with "top:55px;left:33px;" etc... Otherwise you could create an fiddle or something else!?